# How does the embedded js code works to insert form or other dynamic content on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, architecture, cloud

I was wondering how the embedded js (usually from a CDN URL) actually insert another script / html content or collect data on a page dynamically on web page? I am not asking how it decides what to insert / offer on a page, but basically want to understand how it is being made to insert new script / content to collect data. For example, Google Tag Manager or qualaroo, hellobar, etc.

How can I architecture such a service like this using which user can embed a js code and that do the rest like offering content / form based on configuration done.

And how does it communciates with the my server to get content submitted by user.

The goal is that user should not need to change the embedded js code.

Comment: Externaj JS can do anything that a local JS can. And a HTML form element can have the action attribute set to point to an external URL.

Comment: @pawel can you perhaps add more details?

Answer (score 2):

Once embedded code is loaded on the site (either hardcodded to source html code or added dynamically by other javascript code) (whether the embedded script originates from the same server as the page, different server or even CDN-etwork doesn't matter) it will be run as a component of the page.

The script may collect needed data from page content, cookies, javascript variables defined in page outside said script, it may contact it's own server for additional information using AJAX request.

Using said information it will generate html code of wanted form and add it to the page using DOM access.

This form may submit filled data to whatever server needed through this window, new blank window, inserted IFRAME window, or using AJAX request.

No limitations. But to propose optimal solution, you would need to describe your project vision better.

Comment: Maybe Krunal's confusion is just that he thinks there are some limitations for embedded code. Surprise, there are none! That is also why one should be extra cautions before adding foreign script to his page, as it may contain malicious code, either now or in the future.

Comment: Sorry, thank you for your answer, but I'm not clear how such a system like qualaroo works from an architectural point of view!